# How can I fix this TextPad external tool command?

Tags: textpad

When I'm editing a file named:

```
S:\!DJ DAP\PlaylistFormatName.vbs
```

and execute this tool:

[image]

I expect launch of the file

"S:!DJ DAP\PlaylistFormatName-Test.bat"

but get this fail:

```
'S:\!DJ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

How can I fix this?

I'm using TextPad 7.5.1.on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

PS Removing the brackets gives the same fail:

[image]

EDIT: This workaround may suit. It succeeds in the test case, but I am not certain the result is always equivalent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take out the () from the parameters.  When I used "$FileDir\($BaseName)-Test.bat", I could recreate the error.  When I used "$FileDir\$BaseName-Test.bat" it worked as expected.

Or try this:
Command: c:\windows\System32\cmd.exe
Parameters: /c "$FileDir\$BaseName-Test.Bat"
Initial Folder: $FileDir

I swear by an even bigger stack of K&R manuals that it worked.

Comment: I got the same behavior with the ( on either side of the $.

Comment: Thanks, but here that gives the same fail (added to Q). The magic ingredient at yours must be something else. Or perhaps your $FileDir does not contain a space? Could you show a screenshot?

Comment: I swear on a stack of K&R text books, I tried it both ways more than once and it behaved the way I answered it.  Today I couldn't recreate it.

Comment: LOL! Yes, I'm not too surprised to find is it variable. Thanks for trying!